# Is there a way to efficiently add positions to nodes in a binary tree?

Tags: c++, constructor

In the following piece of C++ code, will calling the `Position::left()` many times result in creating multiple objects for the `Node` pointed by `v->left`, each time this function is called? Is this memory efficient or is there a better way to do this?

```
struct Node {                   // a node of the tree
          Elem    element;              // element value
          Node*   par;                  // parent
          Node*   left;                 // left child
          Node*   right;                // right child
          Node() : elt(), par(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL) { } // constructor
        };    

    class Position {
        private:
            Node *v;
        public:
            Position(Node *_v = NULL) : v(_v) {}

            Elem &operator*() { return v->element; }
            Position left() const { return Position(v->left); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Position::left`, since it uses `v->left` without check for null, will continue as long as it's called. Thus, performance is less of a concern than safety.

That said, your `class Position` is doing very little on top of the `struct Node`. It appears unnecessary (and actually ends up hiding fields like `par`).

What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Thanks Nolan for answering. I am creating a list of Position objects. Each position contains a pointer to a tree node. left() essentially returns a Position object for the left child of the node for which it is called. It is through a Position that one can access a node. I am checking Null for v->left while calling left(). So Null value is not my concern here. My question is if I call left() for the same node say 20 times, will it create 20 Position objects for the left child?

Comment: @Naman Jain Semantically, yes. It will create 20 new objects. But, whether or not it "creates" objects is only guaranteed as far as sequence points are reached in code (e.g. IO operations). You would be surprised how much optimization compilers can do.